# VHDL code works in simulation but not in hardware

Tags: spartan-6

I have a SAKURA-G board, I'm trying to program the main FPGA which is a SPARTAN-6 XC6SLX75 CSG484BIV1841, I'm using Xilinx ISE 14.7.

My project files all compile fine and when I simulate the resulting circuit in ModelSim my waveforms behave the way they should be. However when I load them into the FPGA I am not getting the expected output waveforms for AES.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use work.pseudorng;
use work.masked_aes_pkg.all;

entity DOS_AES is
generic (
    N : integer := 2
);
port (
    clock : in STD_LOGIC;
    reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    start : out STD_LOGIC;
    Done : out STD_LOGIC;
    Cipher : out t_shared_gf8(N downto 0)
    );
end DOS_AES;

architecture behav of DOS_AES is 

signal plaintext : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 downto 0) := x"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
signal key : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 downto 0) := x"000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F";
signal Q : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 downto 0) := x"00000000000000000000000000000000";
signal StartxSI : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal en : STD_LOGIC := '1';

-- the provided code processes 8 bits in 20 cycles, so that means
-- 16*20 = 320 cycles. A bit longer than the paper.
signal cycle : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := x"FF";

--shared vars and random numbers for masks need to be in array
signal Binv1xDI : t_shared_gf2(N downto 0);
signal Binv2xDI : t_shared_gf2(N downto 0);
signal Binv3xDI : t_shared_gf2(N downto 0);
signal Bmul1xDI : t_shared_gf4(N downto 0);
signal Zinv1xDI : t_shared_gf2((N*(N+1)/2)-1 downto 0);
signal Zinv2xDI : t_shared_gf2((N*(N+1)/2)-1 downto 0);
signal Zinv3xDI : t_shared_gf2((N*(N+1)/2)-1 downto 0);
signal Zmul1xDI : t_shared_gf4((N*(N+1)/2)-1 downto 0);
signal Zmul2xDI : t_shared_gf4((N*(N+1)/2)-1 downto 0);
signal Zmul3xDI : t_shared_gf4((N*(N+1)/2)-1 downto 0);

signal PTxDI    : t_shared_gf8(N downto 0);
signal KxDI     : t_shared_gf8(N downto 0);

signal DonexSO  : std_logic := '0';
signal CxDO     : t_shared_gf8(N downto 0);

begin

RAND : entity work.pseudorng
    port map (
        clock => clock,
        reset => reset,
        en => en,
        Q => Q
        );

AES : entity work.aes_top
    port map (
    clkxCI => clock,
    RstxBI => reset,
    PTxDI => PTxDI,
    KxDI => KxDI,
    Zmul1xDI => Zmul1xDI,
    Zmul2xDI => Zmul2xDI,
    Zmul3xDI => Zmul3xDI,
    Zinv1xDI => Zinv1xDI,
    Zinv2xDI => Zinv2xDI,
    Zinv3xDI => Zinv3xDI,
    Bmul1xDI => Bmul1xDI,
    Binv1xDI => Binv1xDI,
    Binv2xDI => Binv2xDI,
    Binv3xDI => Binv3xDI,
    StartxSI => StartxSI,
    DonexSO => DonexSO,
    CxDO => CxDO
    );




--I'm not gonna make an independent instance for all 14 random 
-- numbers im gonna need, instead i can split my 128 bit rand number into
-- a bunch of peices.



process (clock, reset)
begin
if (reset = '0') then
    plaintext <= x"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
    key <= x"000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F";
    cycle <= x"FF";
    en <= '1';
    StartxSI <= '0';
    Binv1xDI(0) <= "00";
    Binv1xDI(1) <= "00";
    Binv1xDI(2) <= "00";
    Binv2xDI(0) <= "00";
    Binv2xDI(1) <= "00";
    Binv2xDI(2) <= "00";
    Binv3xDI(0) <= "00";
    Binv3xDI(1) <= "00";
    Binv3xDI(2) <= "00";
    Bmul1xDI(0) <= x"0";
    Bmul1xDI(1) <= x"0";
    Bmul1xDI(2) <= x"0";
    Zinv1xDI(0) <= "00";
    Zinv1xDI(1) <= "00";
    Zinv1xDI(2) <= "00";
    Zinv2xDI(0) <= "00";
    Zinv2xDI(1) <= "00";
    Zinv2xDI(2) <= "00";
    Zinv3xDI(0) <= "00";
    Zinv3xDI(1) <= "00";
    Zinv3xDI(2) <= "00";
    Zmul1xDI(0) <= x"0";
    Zmul1xDI(1) <= x"0";
    Zmul1xDI(2) <= x"0";
    Zmul2xDI(0) <= x"0";
    Zmul2xDI(1) <= x"0";
    Zmul2xDI(2) <= x"0";
    Zmul3xDI(0) <= x"0";
    Zmul3xDI(1) <= x"0";
    Zmul3xDI(2) <= x"0";

    PTxDI(2) <= x"00";
    PTxDI(1) <= x"00";
    PTxDI(0) <= x"00";

    KxDI(2) <= x"00";
    KxDI(1) <= x"00";
    KxDI(0) <= x"00";
elsif (falling_edge(clock)) then
    cycle <= cycle + 1;
elsif (rising_edge(clock)) then
    case (cycle) is
        when x"00" =>
            StartxSI <= '1';
            plaintext <= plaintext + 1;
            en <= '0';
        when x"01" =>
            --update rand numbers
            Binv1xDI(0) <= Q(1 downto 0);
            Binv1xDI(1) <= Q(3 downto 2);
            Binv1xDI(2) <= Q(5 downto 4);
            Binv2xDI(0) <= Q(7 downto 6);
            Binv2xDI(1) <= Q(9 downto 8);
            Binv2xDI(2) <= Q(11 downto 10);
            Binv3xDI(0) <= Q(13 downto 12);
            Binv3xDI(1) <= Q(15 downto 14);
            Binv3xDI(2) <= Q(17 downto 16);
            Bmul1xDI(0) <= Q(21 downto 18);
            Bmul1xDI(1) <= Q(25 downto 22);
            Bmul1xDI(2) <= Q(29 downto 26);
            Zinv1xDI(0) <= Q(31 downto 30);
            Zinv1xDI(1) <= Q(33 downto 32);
            Zinv1xDI(2) <= Q(35 downto 34);
            Zinv2xDI(0) <= Q(37 downto 36);
            Zinv2xDI(1) <= Q(39 downto 38);
            Zinv2xDI(2) <= Q(41 downto 40);
            Zinv3xDI(0) <= Q(43 downto 42);
            Zinv3xDI(1) <= Q(45 downto 44);
            Zinv3xDI(2) <= Q(47 downto 46);
            Zmul1xDI(0) <= Q(51 downto 48);
            Zmul1xDI(1) <= Q(55 downto 52);
            Zmul1xDI(2) <= Q(59 downto 56);
            Zmul2xDI(0) <= Q(63 downto 60);
            Zmul2xDI(1) <= Q(67 downto 64);
            Zmul2xDI(2) <= Q(71 downto 68);
            Zmul3xDI(0) <= Q(75 downto 72);
            Zmul3xDI(1) <= Q(79 downto 76);
            Zmul3xDI(2) <= Q(83 downto 80);

            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(127 downto 120) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(127 downto 120) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);
            StartxSI <= '0';
        when x"02" =>
            --compute 8bit cipher
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(119 downto 112) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(119 downto 112) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24); 

        when x"03" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(111 downto 104) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(111 downto 104) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"04" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(103 downto 96) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(103 downto 96) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"05" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(95 downto 88) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(95 downto 88) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"06" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(87 downto 80) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(87 downto 80) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24); 

        when x"07" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(79 downto 72) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(79 downto 72) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"08" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(71 downto 64) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(71 downto 64) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24); 

        when x"09" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(63 downto 56) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(63 downto 56) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"0A" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(55 downto 48) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(55 downto 48) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24); 

        when x"0B" =>           
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(47 downto 40) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(47 downto 40) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"0C" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(39 downto 32) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(39 downto 32) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24); 

        when x"0D" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(31 downto 24) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(31 downto 24) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"0E" =>   
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(23 downto 16) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(23 downto 16) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when x"0F" =>
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(15 downto 8) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(15 downto 8) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);
        when x"10" =>   
            PTxDI(0) <= plaintext(7 downto 0) xor Q(91 downto 84);
            PTxDI(1) <= Q(91 downto 84) xor Q(99 downto 92);
            PTxDI(2) <= Q(99 downto 92);

            KxDI(0) <= key(7 downto 0) xor Q(23 downto 16);
            KxDI(1) <= Q(23 downto 16) xor Q(31 downto 24);
            KxDI(2) <= Q(31 downto 24);

        when others => en <= '1';
            --ReRoll Rand number--
    end case;
end if;
end process;

start <= StartxSI;
Done <= DoneXSO;
Cipher <= CxDO;

end architecture;
```

The above is the top level, I was wondering if I am doing anything questionable that is causing unexpected behavior in hardware that isn't necessarily caught in software.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure you can see that it's not a free design house. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. You've simply posted a large source file with a few specifications and are wanting people here to debug it for you. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: Would it be more productive to not have the code and ask something more general, what to look for if hardware behaves differently than in simulation?

Comment: To guide you, take a look through some of the other questions on the site, look at the outline of their problem then all the steps they list in trying to solve it. Unfortunately, when you just say you're not getting the expected output but not what it is. Anyway, onwards and upwards :-)

Comment: With Xilinx ISE toolchain, select the RTL (Register Transfer Logic) schematic view, and verify that the ideal RTL logic schematic looks reasonable. This is one way to verify that each module actually synthesized some logic, and did not simply get replaced with a constant 0 value. You can also use ISE’s library of code snippets to find good examples that the synthesis tool recognizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can not be synthesized. In fact I would expect your synthesis tool to thrown a error and halt.

I have not checked you whole code but this is definitely illegal for synthesis:

```
elsif (falling_edge(clock)) then
    cycle <= cycle + 1;
elsif (rising_edge(clock)) then
```

For synthesis you need to have logic which behaves like your HDL code. But there exists no hardware which can work on both edges of the clock. Let alone do one thing on a rising edge and something different on a falling edge.

There are certain HDL language templates which **must** be followed to infer registers. I suggest you have a look at the WWW as there are numerous sources.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, whats the WWW?

Comment: World Wide Web.

Answer (score 1):

There's a major problem around the clock edge detection term you've entered:

```
  elsif (falling_edge(clock)) then
      cycle <= cycle + 1;
  elsif (rising_edge(clock)) then
      case (cycle) is
```

It's important to recognise that VHDL is a glorified netlist. It specifies all the components and interconnections to make a logic circuit, like a netlist does with PCB parts and tracks but with far greater versatility.

Remember that the digital logic circuit design comes first. From that, you write VHDL that produces that circuit. With time and increasing experience, you write VHDL that straightforwardly converts into logic components.

The simulator will simulate your design as closely to the VHDL standard as it can, ideally anyway.

However, the synthesis tool has a different view. Within your FPGA, there is a specific set of logic circuit elements available. These are combinatorial logic (LUT for AND, OR, XOR, NOT) and registers (D-type flip-flops, T-types, SR-types). So the tool tries to make the circuit you told it you wanted out of the parts it has.

What you have written is wish-list VHDL. There is no standard register that can detect rising edge while a falling edge is not occuring, as your design file wants. It may try to make one out of combinatorial logic but it will make a mess.

Don't fall into the other trap of treating VHDL as a programming language, though I don't think you have. It's a descriptor language, it describes a circuit and requires no CPU.

If you stick to these ground rules, and a few others, you'll be able to design away productively and successfully. Just always remember that you're designing a logic circuit, not 'coding' for a CPU.

Meanwhile...

Redesign your 'if' term. Use positive edge-triggered logic here, so 'rising_edge' everywhere. Try the simulation again, synthesize it once the sim' is good.